# Can this FindString function be optimized further, in terms of speed?

Tags: c++, optimization, strings, search

```
int FindStr(char* str, int strsize, char* fstr, int from)
{
    for(int i=from, j=0; i<strsize; i++)
    {
        if(str[i]==fstr[j])
            j++;
        else
            {i-=j; j=0;}

        if(fstr[j]=='\0')
            return i-j+1;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

The function searches for a string `fstr` in `str` and returns its index in `str` if found, otherwise, it will return -1.  It's also possible to specify where to start searching in the string.

My question is, can I optimize this function further? Also, do you see any potential problems in this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some comments to add to the first two of @200_success:

- `strstr` does a good job. Why reinvent?
- sizes are often passed as `size_t` rather than `int`
- modifying the loop variable within the loop is generally considered bad
  practice
- `i -= j` executes on every loop unless there is a match.  Mostly in this
  case `j` is zero so the line has no effect, but it still executes
- if `fstr` is an empty string it returns the wrong result (1)
- add some spaces around operators and after `if`, `for`

Comment: Reinvention is just due to curiosity. Why is loop variable modification bad practice? What if you know what you're doing? As for `i-=j;` I think `if(j>0){i-=j; j=0;}` would cut down on the redundant assignments, but is that going to improve its performance?

Comment: Its not the compiler or the machine you write your code for. It is the next poor slub who has to come along and maintain and fix it. You may know what you are doing. But the next person who looks at the code does not know that you know what you are doing. Writing code that modifies the loop variable is never easy to understand. Writing it a slightly longer way that is easy to read will be unlikely to affect straight line speed. But will make it a thousand times faster to understand and thus fix. If you really know what you are doing then you write 5 paragraphs explaining each optimization :-)

Comment: What you have done here is optimized away an inner loop in the source code. But effectively left it in the machine instructions. The `i-=j` is basically an inner loop reset. So you have gained no significant speed advantage but made the code much harder to read.

Comment: Yes, that's something I need to keep in mind. I always write code without thinking about how other people will perceive it. I need to pay more attention to that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Why is `fstr` treated as a null-terminated string, while the size of `str` has to be explicitly passed in?

What is the expected behaviour when searching for an empty string?

This is a pretty good simple string search.  There are [more sophisticated algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) that try to avoid backtracking.

Comment: Well, I thought that if I want to traverse the string, I'm going to either have to check on each iteration if the end of the string is reached or search for the null-termination and find the size from there. Having the size makes it easier. Having the size of fstr can also help by simplifying the second if statement, now that I think of it.

Comment: Checking for `str[i] != '\0'` is just as easy as checking for `i < strsize`. Null-terminated strings produce a much more natural interface. Furthermore, requiring an explicit `strsize` might force the caller to call `strlen()` first, which is O(n). On the other hand, you have to traverse the string anyway in `FindStr()`, so you get that work for "free".

Comment: Yeah, checking for the null-termination does look better and eliminates the the size parameter. The part about strlen() too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't want to use the `string` library.

The header for `FindStr` should be as follows:

```
char *FindStr(const char *str, const int strsize, const char *fstr, const int from)
```

You should return a pointer to the `char` where the substring is, if it is found, or `NULL` otherwise.  There's no reason for `FindStr` to modify the arguments, so declare them `const`.

Comment: Is there any advantage to using const other than making it clear to the person reading the code that these variables can't be modified?

Comment: @Hex4869 You can pass a string literal into `str` and `fstr` if they are `const`.

Comment: @Hex4869 It'll prevent you or somebody else who modifies the code later from making a mistake and modifying a value that shouldn't be modified.  You may forget or make a mistake.